# Eclipse Formatting - Put wrapped method closing parenthesis on new line

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, eclipse-jdt

I've been mucking with my Eclipse formatter settings and finally found this option:

`org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_selector_in_method_invocation=81`

Which is set from `[Project]` >> `Properties` >> `Java Code Style` >> `Formatter` >> `[Edit]` >> `[Line Wrapping]` >> `> Function Class` >> `Qualified invocations`:

- Set Line Wrapping Policy to: `Wrap all elements, except for first if not necessary`,
- combined with `☑ Force Split, even if line is shorter than maximum width`.

But I'm still left with the formatter now throwing my closing params for wrapped function calls onto a new line.

E.g.:

```
List<DomainObject> domainObjectList = jdbcTemplate.query(
    DaoClass.STATIC_QUERY_STRING,
    new Object[] { bindParam1, bindParam2 },
    new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER },
    new DomainObjectRowMapperClass()
    );
```

Instead of:

```
List<DomainObject> domainObjectList = jdbcTemplate.query(
    DaoClass.STATIC_QUERY_STRING,
    new Object[] { bindParam1, bindParam2 },
    new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER },
    new DomainObjectRowMapperClass()
);
```

Or for another example from the IDE's Formatter on `[Line Wrapping]` >> `> Function Calls` >> `Explict constructor invocations`:

```
/**
 * Explicit constructor invocations
 */
class Example extends AnotherClass {
    Example() {
        super(100,
            200,
            300,
            400,
            500,
            600,
            700);
    }
}
```

Whereas, what I'm looking for is,

```
/**
 * Explicit constructor invocations
 */
class Example extends AnotherClass {
    Example() {
        super(100,
            200,
            300,
            400,
            500,
            600,
            700
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you still want it thrown on a new line - you just want to indent it one level to the left?

Comment: I don't think Eclipse has such option for arguments parenthesis

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I want both. So if I have a multi-line method, than each param should be 1 line, all indented the same, and the closing part should be on a new line be it any of a `]`, `}`, or `)` character with a de-indent of 1 margin (so it lines up to the begining of the method call and the next line of code).